# Why do my Saved-Credentials disappear after a reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

When I save my credentials in `Credential Manager` using the `New-StoredCredential` cmdlet it seems that after a reboot it disappears and I'm forced to rerun the command again if I want to retrieve it with Get-StoredCredential.

My `-Target` argument to `New-StoredCredential` is not a real server, it's just a name, so is that why it disappears?

Comment: Documentation shows the default persistence type is “session”. Did you change this?

Comment: This could be due to the Windows 10 S4U scheduled task bug. [Windows 10 forgets passwords in Outlook, Edge, Chrome, etc](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-forgets-passwords-outlook-edge/)

Answer (score 0):

What is the full command you use to save credentials? There is a `-Persist` flag that you need to use:

Per the [Wiki:](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager/wiki/New-StoredCredential)

> ### -Persist <Cred_Persist>
>
> sets the persistence settings of the credential, possible values are
> [SESSION, LOCALMACHINE, ENTERPRISE]
>
> Default value:    SESSION

You probably want to specify `LocalMachine`, or the credential will be cleared when you log off.